# NUTS Sampler: runaway stepsize

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I've been trying to implement a NUTS sampler according to the Gelman 2014 paper, and I've been finding that my log-stepsize $\log \epsilon$ runs away towards $-\infty$ for reasonable values of $\delta= 0.85$. In turn, the number of steps before the U-Turn condition is met, $L \to \infty$.This doesn't seem to be something that they mention happening in the paper, but [some online versions of the technique](https://github.com/chi-feng/mcmc-demo/blob/master/algorithms/DualAveragingNUTS.js) use a limiter to guarantee the stepsize doesn't go to zero. Is there a theoretical basis or a fix for this?